# Is there a way for having the same string readable and editable from C and Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I have the following problem: an iOS app written with Objective-C (as usual) which uses parts of code written with C. The C code is the core of the application, the code written with Objective-C uses the job done by C and coordinates the whole application.

For doing its job, the C code reads something from a preferences file, whose name is cabled in a C file. Is it possible (in the C code) to read the name of the file at run-time rather then at compile-time? The idea is to modify a string with Objective-C and let the C code to read that string.

Comment: Are you asking how to convert an `NSString` to a `const char *`? Because that's pretty straight-forward.

Comment: When you say "read the name of the file at run-time rather then at compile-time", what file are you talking about?

Comment: I'm talking of the file from which the C code reads something for doing its job

Comment: Still not enough information.  Where is this file in relation to the app?  Do you want the app's Objective-C code to tell the C code the file to read, is that your question?

Comment: I have the C file which reads a file named "userprefs.css". I don't want the C file with this string cabled into the code, but I want to read this string (the name of the file) from a place editable with Objective-C. (hoping it is clear now :))

Comment: Is "cabled"=="hard-coded"?

Comment: Yes it is (did not remember "hard-coded", excuse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `.c` file looks something like this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

static const char *_prefsFilename = "userprefs.css";

bool readPrefs() {

    FILE *fp = fopen(_prefsFilename, "r");
    ....
}
```

Then you simply need to add a function to allow `_prefsFilename` to be set before an attempt is made to use it to open the file:

```
void setPrefsFilename(const char *prefsFilename) {
    _prefsFilename = prefsFilename;
}
```

and ensure you call it before calling `readPrefs()`.

This is all assumption of course, but that's all I have to work with.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you have a hard-coded file name in a C file. That's not a good design; in an iOS application, you never know what your path names are, and the notion of the current folder is muddled in a GUI app. Make the file name a parameter of the C function, and pass it from the Objective C side, along with a full path. Depending on the placement of the file, it can be in your app's bundle, or in the document folder, or somewhere else - you know better.

Yes, you can make file name a variable instead of a constant. The variable datatype would be `char*`.

EDIT re: comments: to work around this, try setting the current folder from the ObjC side. Before calling the C function, call `[NSFileManager setCurrentDirectoryPath:]`, passing the folder where the file is (again, I don't know what it might be). Then the hard-coded file name would work.

Comment: Sadly I cannot modify the signature of the C methods, just I can modify its behaviors...

Comment: @Massimo And you cannot add functions?

Comment: Yes I can, but the C code is really hard and I cannot modify the order with which methods are called.

Comment: @Massimo So you want to change it but cannot.  I don't see how you will get anywhere.  You need to add one additional function before calling any other; something like `setPrefsFilename(const char *filename);`.